# Main method not executing certain methods

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

I am having a problem with some code I wrote for a rock paper scissors game. In my main method I have another method that decides the winner and it isn't performing that method. It's acting as if it isn't even there. Sorry if there is an obvious answer I am just a beginner. For example if it is a tie it won't perform the tie method inside of the decideWinner() method. Thanks for any help

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class appels {
public static Scanner Andrew = new Scanner(System.in);
public static Random Hello = new Random();
public static double compAnswer;
public static String compChoice;
public static String answer;
public static void main(String [] args){
getAnswer(answer);
showCompAnswer();
decideWinner();
}
public static void getAnswer(String answer){
System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors Vs. the computer.\nWhich do you     choose:");
answer = Andrew.nextLine();
}
public static void showCompAnswer(){
compAnswer = Hello.nextDouble();
//System.out.println(compAnswer);
if(compAnswer > .66){
    compChoice = "rock";
}else if(compAnswer>.33 & compAnswer<.66){
    compChoice = "paper";
}else{
    compChoice = "scissors";
}
System.out.println(compChoice);
}
public static void decideWinner(){
if(compChoice == answer){
    tie();
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
}
public static void tie(){
System.out.println("It's a tie.");
}
public static void compWin(){
System.out.println("The computer wins. :(");
}
public static void userWin(){
System.out.println("You win!");
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: That's not the only problem, though... Wasn't sure if I should close as dupe or typo, because 1) You never call anything besides `tie()` at the end, and 2) parameter assignment, among other things. `main()` is *definitely* executing exactly what you told it to execute. There are just other mistakes which cause the program's output to not be what you expect.

Comment: you never call to `compWin` or `userWin`, also you're comparing strings wrong and have 2 `answer` variables - one of them is not used

Comment: Don't use `&` for and, use `&&`.

Comment: compChoice.equalsIgnoreCase(answer)

Comment: Actually, the "and" doesn't need to be there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your final method `decideWinner` is being called, however the code inside that method is bad and incomplete.  First of all when comparing strings you should use `if(compChoice.equals(answer))`  Secondly that only covers the tie scenario you still need to call the compWin and the userWin methods so you need to add some else ifs.

**** Update ****
Took the liberty of cleanng up your code a little bit:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Appels {
    public static Scanner Andrew = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static Random Hello = new Random();
    public static double compAnswer;
    public static String compChoice;
    public static String answer;
    public static void main(String [] args){
        getAnswer();
        showCompAnswer();
        decideWinner();
    }
    public static void getAnswer(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors Vs. the computer.\nWhich do you choose:");
        answer = Andrew.nextLine();
    }
    public static void showCompAnswer() {
        compAnswer = Hello.nextDouble();
        if(compAnswer > .66){
            compChoice = "rock";
        } else if(compAnswer > .33) {
            compChoice = "paper";
        } else{
            compChoice = "scissors";
        }
        System.out.println(compChoice);
    }
    public static void decideWinner(){
        if(compChoice.equals(answer)){
            tie();
        } else if ((compChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("rock") && answer.equals("scissors")) ||
                (compChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("paper") && answer.equals("rock")) ||
                (compChoice.equalsIgnoreCase("scissors") && answer.equals("paper"))) {
            compWin();
        } else {
            userWin();
        }

    }
    public static void tie(){
        System.out.println("It's a tie.");
    }
    public static void compWin(){
        System.out.println("The computer wins. :(");
    }
    public static void userWin(){
        System.out.println("You win!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had no clue that command even existed, but I'm learning.

Comment: No worries.  And be sure to read the comments left by others, they are valid.  Particularly the & vs && as those operators do two very different things.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare string using `==` try to use equals(String) method.

Your parameter passing is not correct, you don't need to use a string parameter to getAnswer(String answer) method. Write it without parameters.

change your code as follows:

```
public static void getAnswer() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors Vs. the computer.\nWhich do you     choose:");
    answer = Andrew.nextLine();
}

public static void decideWinner() {
    if (compChoice.equals(answer)) {
        tie();
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Read this thread related to string comparing.
[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java?lq=1)